# Eclipse Plugin Auto-Fetching

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, m2e

I have an Eclipse project (which is generated via a maven archetype and requires m2e) that I want to deploy to many users. Currently the way I'm telling them to do it is extremely manual, (i.e. download this plugin, download that plugin, download this m2e connector). Is there a way to write down plugin dependencies somewhere in my project so that when the project is imported Eclipse will tell the user "This project depends on you having these Eclipse plugins installed, would you like Eclipse to auto-fetch the plugins for you?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about deploying eclipse plugins first, all of that is available in the basic infrastructure of eclipse.

Whenever you install something via the update manager in eclipse, you don't install plugins as such, but instead you install features, which are groups of plugins plus dependencies to other features. So you have to do 2 things when creating a feature for your plugin:

- List all dependent features in the feature editor.
- On the tab "Sites to visit" you have to list the update site URLs of the dependent features.

P2 update manager will auto-magically discover everything needed during the installation process of your plugin afterwards.

Comment: I never actually mentioned in my original question that I was developing an Eclipse plugin (as a side project) but it does seem as if I can use your answer to solve my problem indirectly.

I still have to tell people "download my eclipse plugin after doing an archetype gen" but at least from there the dependencies will be managed.

Comment: If you just want to give them a "shopping list" for plugins, use File -> Export -> Install -> Software items to file and select all the ones they need. That creates a small file which they can import the same way and which will then drive their update manager.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are several tools created by Eclipse member companies (both with free to use and for-pay editions) that will do exactly what you want.  Both products have the notion of "profiles" that is a pre-set configuration of Eclipse plugins (basically one of the available packages plus a bunch of plugins).  Then once you have this profile configured you can freely share it with our team via email or whatever sharing mechanism the products provide.  Once your team members accept and start "using" the profile those software products will provision exactly what dependencies everyone needs to run your Eclipse projects.

#### [Pulse](http://www.poweredbypulse.com) from Genuitec

They have a [Community edition](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/community_edition.php) and a [Managed Team edition](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/managed_team.php) based on your team's needs.

#### [Yoxos](http://eclipsesource.com/en/products/yoxos/) from EclipseSource

They have a [free plan](https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/) if you want to share your profiles publicly.  If you want to keep them private they have a [pricing plan](https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/plans.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much help this is, but why not use the Eclipse Marketplace if it is available. Saves you the effort to manually download and install the plugin.